# FIltering more then one string with list comprehension

Tags: python, list, filter, list-comprehension

I am working with a list containing urls and wanting to filter out extentions like .jpg, jpeg and .png.

I tried to use list comprehension: [elem for elem in li if elem != ".jpg"] but this would only filter one string.

Is there  a way to solve this?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of checking the equality of the element to a single string, check if the element is present in a set, where each member of the set is a string you want to match against:

```
blacklist = set(['.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png'])
filtered = [elem for elem in li if elem not in blacklist]
```

However, you mentioned you're trying to filter an extension out of a list of urls, which suggests you need to specifically check to see if a string *ends with* the extension, not if the whole string is equal to the extension. In that case, you'd really want to do this:

```
blacklist = ('.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png')
filtered = [elem for elem in li if not elem.endswith(blacklist)]
```

This makes sure `elem` doesn't end with any of the items in `blacklist`.

Comment: Above and beyond, Raise my chalice to that!